# Print to console in SignalR Hub

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

I try to use SignalR, everything works fine except I can't print to console (in visual studio).

Here's the code on server:

```
public class GateSignalr : Hub
{
    public void send(string state) {
        Console.WriteLine("send executed: ");
        Console.WriteLine(state);
        Clients.All.receiveState(state);
    }
}
```

i call method *send* in the server from client, and it work fine, because the server also call method *receiveState* in client

but its not print to console

i already look in visual studio *output* panel, and make it *show output from :* *Build*, *Build Order*, *Debug*, *Javascript Language Service* , *Package Manager*.

but its not there

i'm expecting console to print *"send executed: "*

or maybe it print in somewhere else?

Comment: Use Trace.WriteLine and look at your output window in Visual Studio

Comment: @PetarVučetin thank sir, it print to console now. would u please add it as the answer sir, so i can have 100% answered question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Console.WriteLine` will only print content in a console application. To print in visual studio output, you need to use `Trace.WriteLine` or `Debug.WriteLine` (if you use the Debug configuration which by default defines the DEBUG constant).